# How to find video resolution and aspect ratio of QMediaPlayer video?

Tags: qt, video, qt5, qtmultimedia

This seems too simple, I must be overlooking something?

How do I find the native video size or aspect ratio from a video file being displayed by a `QMediaPlayer`?

The video Resolution, PixelAspectRatio, etc., should be in the MetaData, but I wait for MetaData Update Signals, and wait for seconds after the video `.play()`s, but `isMetaDataAvailable()` always returns false, and `.availableMetaData()` and `.metaData(QMediaMetaData::Resolution).toSize()` always return empty.

There seems to be nowhere else to get the video resolution information, or am I missing something?

I can open the video, play the video at full screen, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QVideoWidget instance as video output for `QMediaPlayer` and retrieve native size of video from QVideoWidget::sizeHint.

```
QSize MyVideoPlayer::getVideoNativeSize(const QString& videoFilePath)
{
    m_mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(0, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface);
    m_mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(m_videoWidget);
    m_mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(videoFilePath));
    connect(m_mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)),
            this, SLOT(OnMediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));

    m_isStoppingVideo = false;
    QEventLoop loop;
    m_mediaPlayer->play();
    while (!m_isStoppingVideo)
    {
        loop.processEvents();
    }
    disconnect(m_mediaPlayer, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)),
                this, SLOT(OnMediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));

    m_mediaPlayer->stop();
    return m_videoWidget->sizeHint();
}

void MyVideoPlayer::OnMediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus mediaStatus)
{
    if (mediaStatus == QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia)
    {
        m_isStoppingVideo = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: not works for live streams

Answer (score 0):

For finding the resolution without metadata, you can take a look at this question from the Qt Forums for a possible solution:

http://forum.qt.io/topic/31278/solved-get-resolution-of-a-video-file-40-qmediaplayer-41/2

> I solved my problem by waiting until the user plays the video and as
>   soon as they do so i get the QGraphicsVideoItems class property:
>   nativeSize.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this problem with `QGraphicsVideoItem`s `nativeSize` property. But the tricky thing is that `nativeSize` becomes valid only after some time since you start playing video. The trick is to connect to special `QGraphicsVideoItem::nativeSizeChanged(const QSizeF &size)` signal that is emitted in case of real `nativeSize` obtainment.